# PHP If variable equals value in dropdown then add 'selected' attribute to option

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, dropdown, forms

I have a drop down menu that checks whether a user has already selected a value by checking database and if they have, I want to add a 'selected' attribute to that option so that when they edit their profile, that option is preselected by what they chose.

Heres an example of what I am trying to accomplish. It works for text inputs but I don't know how to do it with dropdown lists.

So if user selects 'Dog', it gets place in database and adds 'selected' as attribute

```
$animal = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['animal']);
//PHP UPDATE database script -------->

<label>Animal</label></br>
    <select name='animal' value='<?php if($animal == value){ /*Add selected attribute to option */ ?>'>
         <option value="" disabled selected>Select One</option>
         <option value="" disabled>----------------</option>
         <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
         <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
         <option value="Bird">Bird</option>  
    </select>
```

Comment: values go in `<option>` tags not in the `<select>` tag

Comment: Do you also get your dropdown options from a database

Comment: Okay. Is that a standard way of doing things? Cause I add value='<?php echo $animal ?>' to the the select tag the selected option value gets saved to the database, just doesn't add a selected attribute

Comment: See https://html.com/tags/select/ The select tag has no `value` attribute

Comment: No, they are defined in plain html but stores whatever value the user selects to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an array of options

```
$animals = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird'];
```

Then generate the list of options for the `<select>` from that array, checking the selected animal against each one. If it matches, then add the `selected` attribute.

```
<label>Animal</label></br>
<select name='animal'>
     <!-- select the default if none of the options are selected -->
     <option value="" disabled <?php if (!in_array($animal, $animals)) echo 'selected' ?>>
         Select One
     </option>
     <option value="" disabled>----------------</option>
     <?php foreach ($animals as $option) {
        echo "<option ";
        if ($animal == $option) {
            echo 'selected';
        }
        echo ">$option</option>"; 
     ?>
</select>
```

`value` attributes aren't required for your `<option>` elements in this case, since you're using the same values for the option text. (If the value attribute is omitted, the option text will be used as the value.)

Comment: I was actually thinking of doing an array like this just like my nav bar but I couldn't get your version to work for some reason so I just altered it to <?php foreach ($animals as $option) { echo "<option "; if($animal == $option){ echo 'selected';} echo ">$option</option>"; }?> and it works perfectly

Comment: I think I messed up the ternary expression. Sorry about that, I hadn't tested it. I just replaced it with what you used since it's proven to work :)

Comment: Maybe mine doesn't work now. I refresh page and an option is selected but I leave page and come back it's reset

Comment: Since `$animal` is being set from `$_POST`, you'd need to submit a form to see that option selected. It won't stay selected on subsequent page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$animal = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['animal']);
//PHP UPDATE database script -------->

echo '<label>Animal</label></br>
    <select name="animal">
         <option value="" disabled>Select One</option>
         <option value="" disabled>----------------</option>
         <option value="Dog" ' . ($animal == 'Dog' ? 'selected' : '') . '>Dog</option>
         <option value="Cat" ' . ($animal == 'Cat' ? 'selected' : '') . '>Cat</option>
         <option value="Bird" ' . ($animal == 'Bird' ? 'selected' : '') . '>Bird</option>  
    </select>';
```